# I am unable to append text to my textview in android.How do i solve it?Hangman console example

Tags: android, textview, append

```
public class HangmanRoughActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText userLetter;
    private Button checkButton;
    private TextView text;
    protected int count = 6;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        int i;
        userLetter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter);
        checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int myrand = rand.nextInt(4);
        String[] questions = {"srk", "nandu", "kartheek", "kishore", "ravitejaG"}; //some random strings
        final String question = questions[myrand]; //selects a string from the above strings
        final char answer[] = new char[question.length()];
        for (i = 0; i < question.length(); i++) {
            answer[i] = '_'; //if "srk" is selected answer will be _ _ _ initially
        }
        text.setText(answer, 0, i); //if "srk" is selected,setting the textview to _ _ _
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = 0;
                char userEntry = userLetter.getText().charAt(0);
                String stringAnswer = answer.toString();
                if (question == stringAnswer) {
                    text.setText("Congratulations.You won");
                } else {
                    if (count > 0) {
                        int occurence;
                        char c;
                        for (i = 0, occurence = 0; i < question.length(); i++) {
                            c = question.charAt(i);
                            if (userEntry == c) {
                                answer[i] = c; //if 's' is entered by user,answer becomes s _ _
                                occurence++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (occurence == 0) //if the letter entered by user is not present in the question
                        {
                            text.append("You have" + count + "chances to go");
                            count--;
                        }
                        text.setText(answer, 0, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code above is for a simple hangman console game.I am not able to append the line "You have"+count+"chances to go" nor am i able to print "Congratulations.You won".why is it?Sorry for the lengthy code

Comment: Which error did you get? please logcat output

Comment: "I am unable to append text" what does this mean?  If you tell someone you have a problem, it is useful to tell them what the problem is!

Comment: Reference this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159686/android-does-not-append-text-to-textview-properly

Comment: there is no error but i am not able to append to my textview as in the 8th line from the bottom

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K probably has the right answer, but for next time, "I am not able" doesn't mean anything.  Let me explain.  "The wrong text appears", "no text appears", "a piece of text from somewhere else in my code is shown".  My keyboard doesn't have the letter 't' so I can't type "text".  "I have a compiler error".  "I have a runtime crash".  "My cat died when I ran the app".  "The sun stopped shining".  You get the idea....

Comment: yup,i get it .will be more clear next time.thank u

Answer (score 2):

use `String.equals` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase` for comparing strings currently u are using `==` which is used for comparing two object references inside of characters inside a String object.

Comment: Where? `occurence` is int, ah, here `if(question==stringAnswer)`

Answer (score 0):

Try as usual  `text.setText();`. It will work.

```
text.setText("You have"+count+"chances to go");
```

Answer (score 0):

even though i am adding the append statement,i am overriding the textview with the line "text.setText(answer, 0, i);" .So the order of setText and append commands need to be interchanged.